# How to fix nginx 'no input file' when path and permissions are fine?

Tags: nginx, fastcgi

I know this is a common question, but I found no discussion matching exactly with my case.

nginx error log shows:

> FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script:
>   /usr/share/nginx/drupal7/index.php

But:

1. this path is correct, this is the root of my website
2. `www-data` has permission to access it (if I do `su www-data` then `cat /usr/share/nginx/drupal7/index.php` the file is displayed).
3. both nginx root AND `fpm/pool.d/myserver.conf` chroot point to the same folder: `/usr/share/nginx/drupal7`
4. `www-data` user and group have `660` access to this same folder into `pool.d/myserver.conf`
5. `ps -u www-data` shows that it owns nginx and php5-fpm processes
6. I do not have SElinux installed (as some discussions say it could be the problem)

So why can the `www-data` user can access my `index.php` but not FastCGI?
Why does FastCGI try the correct path, but then say it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a chroot set up. When the process is in chroot, the path from the root to the script is like this:

```
/index.php
```

So, you need to modify the paths used with the FastCGI script calls so that they don't include the full directory path to the script file.

Comment: thank you for your answer but i'm not sure to understand... i've read that chroot was to prevent cgi scripts from running outside of www root folder (for security reasons). am I right? if yes, does '/' value breaks the role of chroot?

Comment: Yes, chroot puts a roadblock in the way of scripts attempting to read files on the system outside of the chrooted directory.  No, `/` does not break the role of chroot.

Comment: `chroot` shows a modified filesystem to the applications inside the `chroot`. The `/index.php` that applications see inside the chroot is `/usr/share/nginx/drupal7/index.php` in reality.